# How can I arrange the table and the image in a minipage vertically?

Tags: tables, graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, minipage

I need the table and the image arranged vertically in the minipage instead of horizontally. I also add the pictures used in the code in the end.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[
labelfont=sf,
hypcap=false,
format=hang,
margin=1cm,
justification=RaggedRight,
calcwidth=0.8\linewidth
]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[btc]
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
\textbf{Value of $p$} & 0.2 & 0.35 & 0.5 & 0.65 & 0.8 \\
\textbf{Value of $q$} & 0.8 & 0.65 & 0.5 & 0.35 & 0.2 \\
\midrule
\textbf{Maximum} & 0.58207 & 0.51458 & 0.42131 & 0.28293 & 0.06643 \\
\textbf{The Term of Maximum} & $\pi_{0}$ & $\pi_{0}$  & $\pi_{0}$  & $\pi_{0}$ & $\pi_{0}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{The analysis of ``$p$'' in Geometric catastrophe.}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=12cm]{GeometricP}
\captionof{figure}{The equilibrium distribution curves on different ``$p$''}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok, i really have to ask: Joke? [How can I arrange the tables and the images?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197065)

Comment: Just replace the instruction `\hfill` that's sandwiched between the two `minipage` environments with a blank line.

Comment: @Johannes_B Why? Sorry, I don't understand. I am struggling with my dissertation, so it is really urgent.

Comment: @Mico But the captions are still the same as previous with 3 lines.

Comment: You are asking far too many identical questions. minipages and images are positioned exactly the same way as a letter such as `X` if you put them next to each other they come side by side `XX` if you put a blank line between they come in separate paragraphs one above the other.

Comment: again this optional argument is wrong: `\begin{figure}[btc]` there is no `c` option.

Comment: The widths of the captions are a separate matter, and one which you didn't mention in the body of your posting. As far as I can tell, no useful purpose is served by setting the widths of the two `minipage`s to `0.48\linewidth`. If you choose widths of `1\linewidth` instead, the captions will be able to take up that width as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for that! I have deleted my previous posts. It is my dissertation, so I tried to make the arrangement look good. What about the captions? If I make the table and image vertical arranged, captions still include 3-line content instead of a line.

Comment: @Mico Aha, finally it works.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make (at least) the following changes:

- If you want the minipages to be placed one below the other rather than side-by-side, remove the `\hfill` instruction and simply leave a blank line
- If you want the captions to occupy the full width of the textblock, don't restrict the `minipage` widths to `0.48\linewidth`. Instead, set their widths to `1\textwidth`. By the way, what's the purpose of setting the option `calcwidth=0.8\linewidth` when loading the `caption` package? I would get rid of this option entirely.

Other things to consider:

- Don't use `center` environments inside a minipage; doing so typically adds unwanted vertical whitespace. Just provide the instruction `\centering`.
- If you need a bit more vertical separation between the minipages, provide an instruction such as `\bigskip`.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[
  labelfont=sf,
  hypcap=false,
  format=hang,
  margin=1cm,
  justification=RaggedRight,
  %% calcwidth=0.8\linewidth  % what's the purpose for this?
  ]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
\textbf{Value of $p$} & 0.2 & 0.35 & 0.5 & 0.65 & 0.8 \\
\textbf{Value of $q$} & 0.8 & 0.65 & 0.5 & 0.35 & 0.2 \\
\midrule
\textbf{Maximum} & 0.58207 & 0.51458 & 0.42131 & 0.28293 & 0.06643 \\
\textbf{The Term of Maximum} & $\pi_{0}$ & $\pi_{0}$  & $\pi_{0}$  & $\pi_{0}$ & $\pi_{0}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{The analysis of ``$p$'' in Geometric catastrophe.}
\end{minipage}

% note the all-blank line immediately before this line
\bigskip  % some more vertical separation between the two minipages
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=12cm]{GeometricP}
\captionof{figure}{The equilibrium distribution curves on different ``$p$''}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx, buddy! It really works.

Comment: Okay, absolutely.

Comment: @CharlesYan Please consider **accepting some of the answers** which you claim to have found so useful by clicking on the tick at the top left of the most helpful answer in each case. (Obviously don't do this if nobody has yet answered satisfactorily but your 'Thanks!' and 'It works.' etc. suggest many of your questions have been so answered.